# Pyro Group Validation

Tags: content-management-system, pyro

**Background**

I want to display a link to the admin area if a user is part of the Administrators group
so in my view code I want to do something like;

```
{{ if user:group group_name="administrators" }}
   <a href="{{ url:base }}admin" class="btn red">Admin Area</a>
{{ endif }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after much messing around but I got it to work;

```
{{ if user:group=="admin" }}

.....html code

{{ endif }}
```